# iis web event Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, shared-libraries

I have two .NET MVC web applications. Each of them has it's own solution in Visual Studio 2017. They share a project that provides REST access to a third party API. When compiled and deployed to the IIS server, each of these apps has a copy of that access DLL in its' BIN folder.

When I update shared project with non-breaking change and deploy one of applications, Other one stops working. IIS Reset doesn't solve the problem. I have to recompile and deploy for other application to start working again.
Error seems to be a security one. "Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid", or "Unable to establish TLS connection".

Why is this happening? And what can I do to prevent it?

Thank you!

Comment: There is the same problem in this link, you can refer to it: https://forums.asp.net/t/1762166.aspx?forms+authentication+failed+for+the+request+reason+the+ticket+supplied+was+invalid

Comment: @DingPeng Thank you for the reference BUT they are having problem on a web farm with one server unable to read cookie from another server. 

In my case there is one server with two web apps (actually there is like 20 different web apps) but these two use two copies of the same DLL and seems to mess each other up.

Comment: I think maybe you can use FRT to see what is happening inside IIS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis